# Form won't sent collection to controller if collection contains two elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My application allows the user to store golf scorecards in a SQL database. The user can then retrieve the scorecards, edit them, and save the changes. The Scorecard class contains a list of instances of a Teebox class. The Teebox class contains a name property and a list of instances of a Tee class, which contains yardages for each golf hole.

In the view allowing the user to edit the scorecards (shown in relevant part below), for-loops produce inputs for each Teebox instances and Tee instance. (The below code applies only to 9-hole courses, which is why the second loop iterates 9 times.) If the scorecard contains one Teebox instance, or more than two Teebox instances, then the form submits to the controller properly. However, if the scorecard contains exactly two Teebox instances, then the controller receives "null" for the list of Teebox instances.

Here is a copy of the relevant portion of the code in the view.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.TeeBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TeeBoxes[i].Name)</td>
        @for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TeeBoxes[i].Tees[x].Yardage)</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the first thing to look at should be the fact that you create and editor for `m.TeeBoxes[i].Name` instead of `m.TeeBoxes[i]`, is this intended?

Comment: Yes. I want the user to be able to edit those values, and I want the input elements to appear initially with the stored values that the user previously entered. The above code works as intended except when TeeBoxes contains two elements. If TeeBoxes has one element or more than two, then it works.

Comment: The code you have shown will post correctly with two `TeeBox` elements. If its not, its due to something you have not shown us. but do not use `@for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)` - populate the `Tees` collection with 9 (or 19) objects and use `@for (int x = 0; x < Model.TeeBoxes[i].Tees.Count; x++) { ...`